# What is this site's abreviation?

Tags: discussion

**What happened?**

Well so far I love this site and can't wait until many more movie experts come :), but I was reading one question right now, and one user greeted a new one writing a comment:

"Welcome to MTV"  ...

This is no biggie, but that just doesn't feel right.  I actually thought it was some kind of sarcasm until I asked myself why.

**so..?**

Is "MTV" agreed and accepted ?

[edit] Well I realized also it is on the logo

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I much rather prefer M **&** TV to disassociate ourselves from that Television channel.

Also, before this site merged with the TV proposal, is how we became known as just "movies.SE"

Comment: I agree - M&TV.